# RFC server with .Net connector Gateway not matching

Tags: c#, .net, sap-dotnet-connector, sap-gateway

I'm working on a really simple app running as RFC Server. I installed SAP Netweaver 7.5 trial version. Here is the code to start the server :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(new RfcDestinationConfig());
        RfcServerManager.RegisterServerConfiguration(new RfcServerConfig());

        Type[] handlers = new Type[1] { typeof(StfcConnectionStaticImpl) };

        RfcServer server = RfcServerManager.GetServer("PRD_REG_SERVER", handlers);

        server.Start();
    }
```

Then the handling class :

```
class StfcConnectionStaticImpl
    {
        // The annotation binds the function (name) to its implementation
        [RfcServerFunction(Name = "STFC_CONNECTION")]
        public static void StfcConnection(RfcServerContext serverContext, IRfcFunction function)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("System Attributes: " + serverContext.SystemAttributes.ToString());

            function.SetValue("ECHOTEXT", function.GetString("REQUTEXT"));
            function.SetValue("RESPTEXT", "NCO3: Hello world.");

        }
    }
```

next the Rfc destination config class :

```
public class RfcDestinationConfig : IDestinationConfiguration
{
    public event RfcDestinationManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;

    public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string destinationName)
    {
        if ("PRD_000".Equals(destinationName))
        {
            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.AppServerHost, "172.18.3.22");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.SystemNumber, "00");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.User, "developer");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Password, "Appl1ance");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Client, "001");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.Language, "EN");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.PoolSize, "5");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.MaxPoolSize, "10");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.IdleTimeout, "600");
            return parms;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

and last the Rfc server class :

```
public class RfcServerConfig : IServerConfiguration
{
    public event RfcServerManager.ConfigurationChangeHandler ConfigurationChanged;

    public bool ChangeEventsSupported()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public RfcConfigParameters GetParameters(string serverName)
    {
        if ("PRD_REG_SERVER".Equals(serverName))
        {
            RfcConfigParameters parms = new RfcConfigParameters();
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.GatewayHost, "172.18.3.22");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.GatewayService, "sapgw00");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.ProgramID, "DOT_NET_SERVER");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.RepositoryDestination, "PRD_000");
            parms.Add(RfcConfigParameters.RegistrationCount, "5");
            return parms;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

The server start perfectly  and my registration in the Gateway is ok.

[SAP GATEWAY (SMGW)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4SwN.png)

The problem coming from Logged-on Client because I only see the external client and not the registered program :

[Logged-on Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziNby.png)

My question is why I don't get the Program as Registered Server ?

Is there some SAP configuration to do to allow Program registration ?

If someone can't help me to solve this out, it will be great.

Thank you,

Ronan